# Can new horses from Breath of the Wild be transferred if you've already visited a stable in Tears of the Kingdom?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild, zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

Let's say I have a save file for Breath of the Wild with several registered horses. I then start playing Tears of the Kingdom and [visit a stable to transfer my horses](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/402740/181240).

If I go back to Breath of the Wild to register a new horse, can I transfer that new horse to Tears of the Kingdom? Or can horses only be transferred once per save file?

Comment: I'd assume only unique horses will be transferred. There's probably unique ids associated with all horses and TotK likely keeps track of what ids were imported from BotW.

Answer (score 6):

No. I ran into this same issue on my first playthrough where I did not know your horses transferred over so when I registered my first horse at the stable and learned that my previous horses from Breath of the Wild had transferred, I immediately booted up my BotW save and caught and registered a new horse. This new horse did not transfer over.

I also tried reloading a previous autosave in TotK from before I had visited the stable to see if I could get my new horse to transfer, but even after reloading the save, my new horse did not transfer over. I suspect that the game only transfers horses on creation of a new TotK save file, but I am not certain.